# Why div height fixed to a specific value when height is not set?

Tags: html, css

```css
.section-steps {
  background-color: #ede3e3;
}

.steps-box:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.steps-box:last-child {
  padding-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.app-screen {
  width: 40%;
}

.works-step {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.works-step:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.works-step div {
  color: #e67e22;
  border: 2px solid #e67e22;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.button-app img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-steps">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>How it works &mdash; simple as 1, 2, 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps-box">
      <img src="Resource/img/app-iPhone.png" alt="Omnifood app on iPhone" class="app-screen">
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps-box">
      <div class="works-step">
        <div>1</div>
        <p>Choose the subscription plan that best fits your needs and sign up today.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="works-step">
        <div>2</div>
        <p>Order your delicious meal using our mobile app or website. Or you can even call us!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="works-step">
        <div>3</div>
        <p>Enjoy your meal after less than 20 minutes. See you the next time!</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="button-app"><img src="Resource/img/download-app.svg" alt="App Store Button"></a>
      <a href="#" class="button-app"><img src="Resource/img/download-app-android.png" alt="Play Store Button"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

the rendered output is as following images:

[image]

The height of `<section class="section-steps">` should be equal to the equal to the all child element of `<section class="section-steps">` but as you see in the image the red border indicated the height of `<section class="section-steps">`. But its height should be as green border. Whats problem in my code? I try in several ways such clear: both after floating, but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Did you maybe forget to mention some kind of CSS framework you are using? What is `.row` and  `.col` doing?

Comment: Floating elements are not considered when calculating height of an element.

Comment: Ya sorry, your example does not reproduce the output you're showing as your problem and like connexo pointed out we don't have enough insight into other potential influences like the additional css classes and overall DOM layout to effectively troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I am using http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ css framwork.

Comment: FWIW @NazninAkter, unless you need to support older browsers, I would use a grid system that uses flexbox and not floats. The one you chose is bit _"outdated."_

Answer (score 0):

When you float something, it pops it out of the containing element, so the height of `.section-steps` cannot be determined by its child elements.

View the snippet full-screen to see the effect. (To prevent the wider paragraph from going below the (2), you will need to give it flexible widths using [flex-box CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).)

```css
  .section-steps{
        background-color: #ede3e3;
    }
    .steps-box{
       
    }
    .steps-box:first-child{
         text-align: right;
        padding-right: 3%;
         margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .steps-box:last-child{
       padding-left: 3%;
        margin-top: 75px;
    }
    .app-screen{
        width: 40%;
    }
    .works-step{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .works-step:last-of-type{
        margin-bottom: 80px;
    }
    .works-step span{
        color: #e67e22;
        border: 2px solid #e67e22;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 55px;
        width: 55px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 150%;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }
.works-step p { 
display: inline-block;
}
    
    .button-app img{
        height: 50px;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="section-steps">
       <div class="row">
          <h2>How it works &mdash; simple as 1, 2, 3</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps-box">
             <img src="Resource/img/app-iPhone.png" alt="Omnifood app on iPhone" class="app-screen">
          </div>
          <div class="col span_1_of_2 steps-box">
             <div class="works-step">
                <span>1</span>
                <p>Choose the subscription plan that best fits your needs and sign up today.</p>
             </div>
             <div class="works-step">
                <span>2</span>
                <p>Order your delicious meal using our mobile app or website. Or you can even call us!</p>
             </div>
             <div class="works-step">
                <span>3</span>
                <p>Enjoy your meal after less than 20 minutes. See you the next time!</p>
             </div>
             <a href="#" class="button-app"><img src="Resource/img/download-app.svg" alt="App Store Button"></a>
             <a href="#" class="button-app"><img src="Resource/img/download-app-android.png" alt="Play Store Button"></a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
```